# Can't access to my firestore collection via flutter app

Tags: flutter, firebase, dart, google-cloud-firestore

I'm developing a flutter app that requires registration. so I used Firebase to auth and store. the authentication works fine. the user can sign up/in and sign out using `createUserWithEmailAndPass` function, as well as reset password.

The problem is the register page requires a name to be displayed later in profile, so I watch a tutorial in youtube to connect to firestore and followed his steps. so once the user clicks on Sign Up button I want that name to be stored with the email provided and displayed in profile page.

But unfortuinality, this shows an error.
[image]

Here's the AuthService code:

```
class AuthService{

  final FirebaseAuth _auth = FirebaseAuth.instance;

  //sign up with email & password
  Future signUp(String email, String password, String name) async {
    try{
      await _auth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email: email, password: password);
      await addUserDetail(name, email);
    } 
    on FirebaseAuthException catch (e){
      Utils.showSnackBar(e.message, Colors.red);
    }
  }

  //add user details
  Future addUserDetail(String name, String email) async {
    await FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('users').add({
      'name': name,
      'email': email,
    });
  }
}
```

And here is the Sign up pressed function:

```
class SignUpScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  final  VoidCallback showLogIn;
  const SignUpScreen({super.key, required this.showLogIn,});

  @override
  State<SignUpScreen> createState() => _SignUpScreenState();
}

class _SignUpScreenState extends State<SignUpScreen> {

  final _nameCont = TextEditingController();
  final _emailCont = TextEditingController();
  final _passwordCont = TextEditingController();
  final _passwordConCont = TextEditingController();
  final _formKey = GlobalKey<FormState>();
  final AuthService _auth = AuthService();

  @override
  void dispose() {
    _nameCont.dispose();
    _emailCont.dispose();
    _passwordCont.dispose();
    _passwordConCont.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }

......................................

                  ElevatedButton(
                    onPressed: () async {
                      final isValid = _formKey.currentState!.validate();
                      if(!isValid) return;
                      showDialog(
                        context: context,
                        builder: (context) => const Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator()),
                      );
                      await _auth.signUp(
                        _emailCont.text.trim(),  
                        _passwordCont.text.trim(),
                        _nameCont.text.trim(),
                      );
                      navigatorKey.currentState!.popUntil((route) => route.isFirst);
                    },
                    style: ElevatedButton.styleFrom(
                      padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 138, vertical: 13),
                      shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                      borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(30)),
                    ),
                    child: const Text(
                      'Sign Up',
                      style: TextStyle(fontSize: 22, letterSpacing: 1.5),
                    ),
                  ),
```

I checked my collection name and it's correct.
And I have searched a lot but couldn't find answers.

Please, help me out I'm running out of time.

Answer (score 1):

Actually, it works fine in real device, I don't know why it doesn't work in vertiual devices.